# jhipster elasticsearch connect

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, jhipster

I have a local elasticsearch on localhost:9200, when I enter the address to browser I got this:

```
{
  "name" : "DESKTOP-RS83PFC",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "b7GwBWOmTnKtzdYuebH8Ww",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.5",
    "build_hash" : "6a37571",
    "build_date" : "2017-12-04T07:50:10.466Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

And I have 2 java property in my backend:

```
 data:
        elasticsearch:
            cluster-name: elasticsearch
            cluster-nodes: localhost:9200
```

When I try to run my app I get this error:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{pwMxs6AGTYePz2M9oTR-NQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9200}]
```

How to connect to this elastic server with my Jhipster(v5.0.0-beta.3) backend?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a try by adding `transport.host: localhost` property in `elasticsearch.yml` file.

Hope it helps..!!